# feature-request: add days since last question asked to user-page

Tags: feature-request

On a user-page, in the info tab (which shows 'name', 'member for', 'seen' etc) add a line which shows the number of days elapsed since the user ased a question. To purpose of this is to raise user awareness about the frequency with which they ask questions, and hopefully increase the question contribution rate for IT Security.

Edit: I made this suggestion because currently (mid-2011) [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8431/it-security) shows that the IT Security 'questions per day' could use improvement. Area 51 shows the 'answer ratio' as excellent.

Comment: Nice idea. To generalize, I would also add "last answer".

Comment: Driving up the question rate just to increase a number isn't usually a good idea. Far worse than having a trickle of questions is a flood of *bad* questions...

Comment: @Shog9 I am confused. The Area 51 site gives five statistics and some comments about each. I want IT Security to progress out of Beta. When I see a statistic that could use improvement, what should I do?

Comment: @this.josh: work to promote the site. Get more users involved, and you'll get more questions. Getting a small handful of users to post questions when they don't actually *need answers* isn't a good long-term solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not a good idea. We have people here that are good to answer questions and people who ask good question. These two groups do not necessary have an intersection.

Besides, we will/have attract(ed) experts here. Those people do not necessarily need to ask questions, or just a few. This statistic could be seen as devaluing. 
Maybe if we had a page dedicated to statistics, this would have its place on it. But I do not think it's a good thing to display publicly and prominently.

Comment: What about if this information was visible only to the user? How about something a bit more "stats"-ish, like "Last question asked on *<date>*, Last answered on *<date>*"?

Comment: Well if it's only statistical and clearly stated, thus having no impact on the user, I'm ok with this. But we do not want to create a "question-aked"-rate thing.

Comment: I agree - this shouldnt be a score-type of thing.